# Using series to approximate log(2)

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
double k = 0; 
int l = 1;
double digits = pow(0.1, 5);

do 
{
    k += (pow(-1, l - 1)/l);
    l++;
} while((log(2)-k)>=digits);
```

I'm trying to write a little program based on an example I seen using a series of Σ_(l=1) (pow(-1, l - 1)/l) to estimate log(2);

It's supposed to be a guess refinement thing where time it gets closer and closer to the right value until so many digits match.

The above is what I tried but but it's not coming out right. After messing with it for quite a while I can't figure out where I'm messing up.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.  For this question, you really do need to include your set of unit tests as part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to extimate the natural logarithm of 2 by its Taylor series expansion:

```
         ∞ (-1)n + 1
 ln(x) = ∑ ――――――――(x - 1)n
         n=1   n
```

One of the problems of your code is the condition choosen to stop the iterations at a specified precision:

```
do { ... } while((log(2)-k)>=digits);
```

Besides using `log(2)` directly (aren't you supposed to find it out instead of using a library function?), at the second iteration (and for every other even iteration) `log(2) - k` gets negative (-0.3068...) ending the loop.

A possible (but not optimal) fix could be to use `std::abs(log(2) - k)` instead, or to end the loop when the absolute value of `1.0 / l` (which is the difference between two consecutive iterations) is small enough.

Also, using `pow(-1, l - 1)` to calculate the sequence 1, -1, 1, -1, ... Is really a waste, especially in a series with such a slow convergence rate.

A more efficient series (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)) is:

```
           ∞     1 
 ln(x) = 2 ∑  ――――――― ((x - 1) / (x + 1))2n + 1
           n=0 2n + 1
```

You can extimate it without using `pow`:

```
double x = 2.0;  // I want to calculate ln(2)

int n = 1;
double eps = 0.00001,
       kpow = (x - 1.0) / (x + 1.0),
       kpow2 = kpow * kpow,
       dk,
       k = 2 * kpow;

do {
    n += 2;
    kpow *= kpow2;
    dk = 2 * kpow / n;
    k += dk;
} while ( std::abs(dk) >= eps );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and better choice of series.